# Array Pointer not returned the expected value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Per a different thread I learned that using '&' with an array doesn't return a double pointer but rather a pointer array.

```
int x[9] = {11, 22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99};
int (*xpt)[9] = &x;    <---This is the focus of this thread.
```

The following code compiles and executes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () 
{
    int x[9] = {11, 22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99};
    int (*xpt)[9] = &x;

    printf("xpt[0] = %d\n", xpt[0]);
    printf("xpt[0][0] = %d\n", xpt[0][0]);
    printf("xpt[0][1] = %d\n", xpt[0][1]);
    printf("*xpt[0] = %d\n", *xpt[0]);
    printf("*xpt[1] = %d\n", *xpt[1]);

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output.

```
> ./runThis
xpt[0] = 155709776
xpt[0][0] = 11
xpt[0][1] = 22
*xpt[0] = 11
*xpt[1] = 32766
```

The questions pertain to the output.
Since xpt is an array pointers (I assume) **xpt[0]** is simply displaying the address of the first value 11.

I was a bit surprised that the following 2 lines worked.

```
  xpt[0][0] = 11
  xpt[0][1] = 22
```

After thinking about it, it almost makes sense as I was thinking **xpt[0]** and ***xpt** could be used interchangeably until the following two lines disproved that :

```
  *xpt[0] = 11
  *xpt[1] = 32766
```

Why does ***xpt[0]** return the expected value but not ***xpt[1]**?

Comment: *Since xpt is an array pointers  (I assume)* - `xpt` is a pointer to array of 9 `int`s. Don't assume, but find the docs and verify.

Comment: I have yet to find a single reference that does a very good job explaining pointers in various scenarios. Usually I have to find various links and piece together an explanation. If you have reference to a URL which does a good job, please post.

Comment: For this specific issue you can use [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*xpt%29%5B9%5D). It is reading the docs for you :) But there is so-called [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `(*xpt)[0]` to get the array elements. Otherwise you are having undefined behavior here. Because you are accessing some memory that will be out of the bound or that you shouldn't/ or you don't have permission to.

Also don't be suprised by `xpt[0][0]` that is equivalently what I said above.

The reason is - `*xpt[1]` is dereferencing a memory that is not even pointing to any elements of the array. This is undefined behavior.

```
123456789XXXXXXXXXX
^        ^
|        |
xpt[0]   xpt[1]
```

Here `1234....` denotes the elements of the array and `xpt[1]` points to out of the array.

Also array subscripts (`[]`) has higher precedence than dereference(`*`). As a result when you write `*xpt[1]` it will first calculate `xpt[1]` and then try to get it's value, which is causing undefined behavior in your program.

Also to give you a better intuitive idea about how to understand this -
 Pointers operations are dictated by what it points to. Here when you declared

```
int (*xpt)[9] = &x;
```

it is saying that `xpt` is a pointer to an `int` array of 9 elements. Now you initialize with the address of `x`. Now think what it points to ? It is the array object `x`. So what will it point to if we do this `xpt[1]`? Next array object (if any). So that's why we get to the address first and then dereference it to get to the array `(*xpt)` and now use array subscript to get the correct elements.

```
int* xpt = &x
```

is something compiler will complain about. It is assigning type `int(*)[9]` to `int*` - this is wrong. The type matters for pointers - that's why compiler will complain.

One more interesting thing you may ask why `*xpt[0]` is `11` not `22` or `33` etc?

The thing is `xpt[0]` is the array to which `xpt` was pointing to. The array `xpt[0]` converts (decays) into pointer to *first* element (`xpt[0][0]`) of the array(`xpt[0]`), and then you dereferenced (`*xpt[0]`)it. That's why you got the first element of the array as the value.

Comment: in fact your declaration of xpt was a clue - you did `int (*xpt)[9] = &x;` for the same reason, except the compiler complained when you tried `int *xpt[9] = &x;`

Comment: @pm100.: i am still editing - including this too...Please give me some time.

Comment: @pm100.: check please